# Is an athlete's heart rate after exercise greater than a non-athlete

Tags: human-biology, breathing, heart-output

I was just wondering 
And if it is greater or lower how does this benefit an athlete 
Also what is the averaged number of heart beats per minute

Comment: Do you mean for example *a)* if a trained 5 k runner and a regular person both ran 5 k in the same time, or *b)* if a trained athlete and a regular person both exercised as hard as they can. For your second part, do you mean are people with lower natural heart rates more/less able to become athletes? Also for your third part, do you mean resting heart rate?

Comment: If they both ran througsame distance

Comment: For second part if persons with a lower heart rate better abled to become athletes and for the third part the resting heart rate

Comment: The answer is that resting heart rates vary a lot.  Typical rates can be found with Google.  For an active person or athlete, capacity increases with training (that's what training is FOR), so (all else being equal) doing the same distance/time causes less increase in pulse rate.

Comment: @ user21887- The Heart can only endure a certain amount of pumps and then it fails, So speeding up the limited amount of pumps just for exercise is only shorting your life expectancy in reality.

Comment: @ user21887- Look into how many deaths occur in Soccer from heart failure, Those guys were in absolute great shape, How did they have a heart attack? They used up there limited heart pumps from years of extreme exercise and died a rather premature death in my eyes. If only they knew it was self involuntary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whilst exercising, the heartbeat of a non-athletic individual is faster than that of an athletic individual. The untrained heart beats faster, but less efficiently than that of an athlete. Both the maximum, and the resting heart rate of an athletic individual are lower than the average heartbeat. In a non-athletic individual, the heart rate when resting is about 60 to 90 beats per minute, whilst in athletes it can drop below 40 beats per minute.

> When you exercise, the heart works harder when other muscles in the body pump more blood back to the heart. The major muscles of the legs have large veins that will fill during the relaxation stage of the movement, and the muscle contraction in the active movement pushes the blood back into the circulatory system. Increasing blood flow triggers a faster heartbeat. Because the heart muscle of conditioned athletes enlarges and strengthens, the hearts of athletes pump more blood per beat. [1](http://www.livestrong.com/article/385209-why-do-athletes-have-a-lower-heart-rate/)